# IF AND SharePoint Calculated Field

Tags: sharepoint

I have been researching this and I have found several different iterations of the formula, but I just can't get mine to work. I am trying to create an if/and formula in a calculated field. I am trying to show data based on three criteria.

1. If the create date is greater than month 2 and less than month 8 then `OCTOBER 1`
2. If the account change type is `Immediate: Error or Business Case` then `MONTH([CreateDate])+1` and `1`.
3. Otherwise `MARCH 1`

This is the formula I have:

```
=IF(AND([Created]>2,[Created]<8),"OCTOBER 1",IF([Account Change Type]="Immediate:  Error or Business Case"),"ASAP","MARCH 1"))
```

These are the forums I have looked at and still can't get it:

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162394/sharepoint-calculated-column-if-function-and-date)

[Social TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/946fc5e7-e681-4a5e-9142-913d6fbb916a/calculated-column-with-if-or-and)

[StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104048/creating-a-status-column-if-statement-calculated-column)

Comment: I just realized the formula provided "ASAP" instead of the MONTH([CreateDate])+1 and day 1 result. Either will work for me. -- Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer that pops to mind is that you have an extra parentheses at the end of that formula. If you want to test these formula syntax wise, just put them in Excel.

If you're having another issue beyond that, can you provide an error or specific symptom of some sort?

Comment: Thank you!  That worked! I just pasted the formula into Excel and replaced column references with cell references and found the error there.

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to check this one as the answer. :)